# Efficiently get the number of children with specific name using XML and R

Tags: xml, r, xpath, xml-parsing

Using R and the package XML I'm parsing huge XML files. As part of the data handling I need to now, in a long list of nodes, how many children of specific name each node has (the number of nodes can exceed 20.000)

My approach at the moment is:

```
nChildrenWithName <- xpathSApply(doc, path="/path/to/node/*", namespaces=ns, xmlName) == 'NAME'
nChildren <- xpathSApply(doc, path="/path/to/node", namespaces=ns, fun=xmlSize)
nID <- sapply(split(nChildrenWithName, rep(seq(along=nChildren), nChildren)), sum)
```

Which is as vectorized as I can get it. Still I have the feeling that this can be achieved in a single call using the correct XPATH expression. My knowledge on XPATH is limited though, so if anyone knows how to do it I would be grateful for some insight...

best Thomas

Answer (score 3):

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlTreeParse(
  system.file("exampleData", "mtcars.xml", package="XML"),
  useInternalNodes=TRUE      )
xpathApply(xmlRoot(doc),path="count(//variable)",xmlValue)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the total number of nodes - not per parent. I might have formulated the question a bit odd. MiMo's example describes what I wanted to achieve...

Comment: Yes, please always add sample data as usually requested. This would have made it clear.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly the question, there is a XML like:

```
<path>
  <to>
    <node>
      <NAME>A</NAME>
      <NAME>B</NAME>
      <NAME>C</NAME>
    </node>
    <node>
      <NAME>X</NAME>
      <NAME>Y</NAME>
    </node>
  </to>
  <to>
    <node>
      <NAME>AA</NAME>
      <NAME>BB</NAME>
      <NAME>CC</NAME>
    </node>
  </to>
</path>
```

and what is wanted is the number of `NAME` elements under each `node` one - so 3, 2, 3 in the example above.

This is not possible in XPath 1.0: an expression can return a list of nodes or a single value - but not a list of computed values.

Using XPath 2.0 you can write:

```
for $node in /path/to/node return count($node/NAME)
```

or simply:

```
/path/to/node/count(NAME)
```

(You can test them [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi))

Comment: Thanks - you got the question right. Good to know it cannot be done with the current xpath implementation. I will look up for an update to the XML package with support for xpath 2

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know R, but it seems to me that the XML/XSLT/XPath stuff is based on the Saxon processor, that supports 2.0

Comment: Hmm... As far as I can see it is based on the libxml2 C parser which AFAIK only supports xpath 1.0... But thanks again...

Comment: In case you find a solution R/XPATH 2.0, please post it here. Looks like there is none in Omegathat.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the example mentioned by [MiMo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920539/mimo)

```
<path>
  <to>
    <node>
      <NAME>A</NAME>
      <NAME>B</NAME>
      <NAME>C</NAME>
    </node>
    <node>
      <NAME>X</NAME>
      <NAME>Y</NAME>
    </node>
  </to>
  <to>
    <node>
      <NAME>AA</NAME>
      <NAME>BB</NAME>
      <NAME>CC</NAME>
    </node>
  </to>
</path>
```

To get number of children under /path/to/node

```
library(XML)
doc = xmlParse("filename", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
rootNode = xmlRoot(doc)
childnodes = xpathSApply(rootNode[[1]][[1]], ".//NAME", xmlChildren)
length(childnodes)
[1] 3
```

It will give you 3, similarly to get number of children under second node just pass the index accordingly,

```
childnodes = xpathSApply(rootNode[[1]][[2]], ".//NAME", xmlChildren)
length(childnodes)
[1] 2
```

I hope it will help you.