# Counting XML nodes in R

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I'm trying to parse this XML table, but I'm having trouble counting the number of "var" nodes. My code so far is below. I would like to be able to replace the 16597 with a generalizable value so that I can use this code for other similar tables. I need to do this in R, not in XPATH.

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
url = "http://api.census.gov/data/2000/sf3/variables.xml"
doc = xmlParse(url)
root = xmlRoot(doc)
xml.data = xmlToList(doc)

id = NULL
label = NULL
concept = NULL
for(i in 1:16597){
  id[i] = xml.data[[1]][[(i+2)]][["id"]]
  label[i] = xml.data[[1]][[(i+2)]][["label"]]
  concept[i] = xml.data[[1]][[(i+2)]][["concept"]]
}

scraped.data = data.frame(id, label, concept)
```

I tried this based off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948339/efficiently-get-the-number-of-children-with-specific-name-using-xml-and-r) but got 0.

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse(url)
xpathApply(xmlRoot(doc),path="count(//vars)",xmlValue)
```

Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: Not able to download the link you provided. Anyway, does `for (i in 1:(length(xml.data[[1]])-2))` work?

Comment: Of course. Can't open the link even in a browser.

Comment: It's a huge file and sometimes takes up to 10 minutes to load. That's why I'm trying to parse it this way. I just sent it to someone else and they were able to open it, so let's wait to see if any other SO users can open it successfully. Thanks for the attempt!

Comment: PS; your code worked, but I don't understand *why* you knew to do that. For exmaple, length(xml.data[[1]][[1]]) gives 5 and length(xml.data[[1]][[4]]) gives 3. How can I see the structure well enough to be able to reproduce what you did?

Comment: It appears that `xml.data` is a nested `list`, in the sense that the elements of `xml.data` are also lists. So the first element of `xml.data` (`xml.data[[1]]`) is a list and in your loop you select each element of that list and get your desired values. It's also obvious that you don't want the first two elements (the `i+2` index) and so the length of `xml.data[[1]]` minus 2 must match the number you hard-coded in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the loop and just "rbind" your list.

```
y <- ldply(xml.data[[1]], "rbind")
dim(y)
[1] 16599     6
head(y)
  .id        id                                                                                                                                  label
1 var       for                                                                                                           Census API FIPS 'for' clause
2 var        in                                                                                                            Census API FIPS 'in' clause
3 var PCT022034               Total:  Not living in an MSA/PMSA in 2000:  Different house in 1995:  In United States in 1995:  In an MSA/PMSA in 1995:
4 var PCT022035 Total:  Not living in an MSA/PMSA in 2000:  Different house in 1995:  In United States in 1995:  In an MSA/PMSA in 1995:  Central city
5 var PCT022032                                                                   Total:  Not living in an MSA/PMSA in 2000:  Different house in 1995:
6 var PCT022033                                        Total:  Not living in an MSA/PMSA in 2000:  Different house in 1995:  In United States in 1995:
```

Comment: Thank you for this, btw 'library(plyr)' at the top would be helpful